# Spotify API field filtering

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to use field filtering to pick out specific nested fields, and it seems to me like I'm hitting a limit for nesting.
Here's the filter I'm using: `items(date_added, track(name, album(artists(name))))`

and here's the curl command I'm trying (built with the new developer console):

`curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/<user_id>/playlists/<playlist_id>/tracks?fields=items(date_added%2C%20track(name%2C%20album(artists(name))))" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

This call works and everything looks good until it gets to the artists field. It doesn't seem to be filtering down artist fields. I just want the artist name in this case. Here's a snippet of what I'm getting back:

```
"items": [
    {
      "track": {
        "album": {
          "artists": [
            {
              "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/3t69c5VItBx3GCrnkcYHEL"
              },
              "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3t69c5VItBx3GCrnkcYHEL",
              "id": "3t69c5VItBx3GCrnkcYHEL",
              "name": "Imagined Herbal Flows",
              "type": "artist",
              "uri": "spotify:artist:3t69c5VItBx3GCrnkcYHEL"
            }
          ]
        },
        "name": "Floating"
      }
    }...
];
```

As you can see, I'm getting the full artist object. Can someone help me understand why I can't filter the fields for that?

Comment: just want to comment that I've run in to the same exact issue today, can't seem to filter down to artist's name property